# Is there an object able to chain successive method calls

Tags: java, java-8, declarative

I have several methods that have the following pattern:

```java
int status = method0();
if(status = success){
  status = method1();
}
if(status = success){
  status = method2();
}
if(status = success){
  status = method3();
}
if(status = success){
  status = method4();
}
return status
```

And I would like to make this more readable. I imagine something like this:

```java
final CommandPipe pipe = new CommandPipe();
status = pipe.next(() -> method0(arg0))
              .next(() -> method1(arg1))
              .next(() -> method2(arg2))
              .next(() -> method3(arg3))
              .next(() -> method4(arg4))
              .getResult();
return status;
```

Is there an object doing this in Java 8 ?

Comment: You can do this with a `List<IntSupplier>` (or similar) and a loop.

Comment: I assume you meant `if(status == success)` instead of `if(status = success)` - comparison and not assignment, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now no.
Since its your business case frameworks wont provide such a things.
You have to construct yourself or else you can use CompletableFuture.supplyAsync and thenApply methods successively for better thread utilization of resources.

Comment: I accepted this response as it exactly answers my question: it's a "no" with a CompletableFuture based response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List<IntSupplier>` and a for loop:

```
int method(List<IntSupplier> list) {
  int status = success;
  for (Iterator<IntSupplier> it = list.iterator(); status == success && it.hasNext();) {
    status = it.next().get();
  }
  return status;
}
```

Invoke like:

```
int status = method(List.of(
    () -> method0(arg0),
    () -> method1(arg1) /* etc */));
```

(Sure, List.of is a Java 9 method. Construct your list however you like).

Your `CommandPipe` class would be quite easy to write:

```
class CommandPipe {
  int status = success;

  CommandPipe next(IntSupplier supplier) {
    if (status == success) {
      status = supplier.get();
    }
    return this;
  }

  int getResult() { return status; }
}
```

Invoke like you wrote in the question.

Comment: You don't invoke `method()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and a proposition of another way of achieiving the initial aim. 

I indeed thought it was quite simple to implement but could not find an object providing such simple implementation and was quite surprised. I asked it here in order to avoid reinventing the wheel 

Comment: As long as you don’t invoke `method`, the `List.of(…)` won’t work with lambda expressions, as it lacks a target type. On the other hand, for this use case, a varargs method would eliminate the need to use `List.of(…)`. `int method(IntSupplier... all) { for(IntSupplier s: all) { int status = s.getAsInt(); if(status != success) return status; } return success; }`

Comment: @EnzoMolion how could a builtin solution be simple? A general purpose tool has no knowledge of your intended semantics, i.e. the `int` result value and the meaning of `success`. You have to tell it what you want and that’s what make it nontrivial. E.g. `Stream.<IntSupplier>of(() -> method0(arg0), () -> method1(arg1) /* etc */) .mapToInt(IntSupplier::getAsInt) .filter(i -> i != success) .findFirst() .orElse(success)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest is to implement such a type yourself, like:

```java
public class CommandPipe<T> {
    private Predicate<T> predicate;
    private T lastResult = null;
    private boolean firstInvotion = true;
    public CommandPipe(Predicate<T> predicate) {
      this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public CommandPipe next(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        boolean doStep;

        if (firstInvotion) {
            firstInvotion = false;
            doStep = true;
        } else {
            doStep = predicate.test(lastResult);
        }

        if (doStep) {
            lastResult = supplier.get();
        } else {
            // error handling
        }

        return this;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return lastResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I indeed thought it was quite simple to implement but could not find an object providing such simple implementation and was quite surprised. I asked it here in order to avoid reinventing the wheel 

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static method with varargs like this.

```
public static int pipe(IntSupplier... methods) {
    int success = 0;
    int status = success;
    for (IntSupplier m : methods) {
        status = m.getAsInt();
        if (status != success)
            break;
    }
    return status;
}
```

and

```
int status = pipe(
    () -> method0(arg0),
    () -> method1(arg0),
    () -> method2(arg0),
    () -> method3(arg0),
    () -> method4(arg0));
```